# expected ‘char ** restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[x]’

Tags: c

I've never understood this error and I keep running into similar one's and it's really frustrating as I can't find a solution to it. (If there is another one please don't bash on me as I couldn't find it).

Looking at a simple piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char s[10];
    int x = strtol(argv[1], &s, 10);
    printf("%d", x);
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

I keep receiving these errors, but I don't really understand why:

> warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strtol’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>     int x = strtol(argv[1], &s, 10);

and

> note: expected ‘char ** restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’

When I change `char s[10]` to `char *s` I receive a segfault on the line that uses strtol. I don't understand what's going wrong, could someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `char s[10]` to `char *s` is the correct way to address the compile error.  `strtol`'s second argument is supposed to be a pointer to a *pointer variable*, which it will initialize to point somewhere *within* the string that is its first argument.  `char s[10]` does not declare a pointer variable, `char *s` does.

The only explanation I can think of, why this program might crash, is that you didn't pass it any arguments.  In that case `argc` will be less than 2 and `argv[1]` will be a null pointer (or possibly not even initialized).  You need to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s integer\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *s;
    long x = strtol(argv[1], &s, 10);
    printf("x: %ld\n", x);
    printf("s: '%s'\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Incidentally, in C, for historical reasons, preferred style is to put the opening curly brace of a function definition on its own line, even if all other opening curly braces are "cuddled".

Answer (score 2):

&s is referring to the address of the array. It is effectively a pointer to a pointer. What you want is to pass in the array name s which is a pointer pointing to the first character of the array s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char s[10];
    int x = strtol(argv[1], s, 10);
    printf("%d", x);
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable of `char *` and then pass this to function.
It is not possible to pass array that way as it will not decay to `char **`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char s[10];
    char* s_ptr; //New variable, char *

    int x = strtol(argv[1], &s_ptr, 10);
    printf("%d", x);
    printf("%s", s_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

See documentation of `strtol` function:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: Hmm, this still seems to be causing a segfault.

Comment: So it is time to debug where it happens. It it happens in `strtol` function, it is not because of `s_ptr` pointer.